# Test for convergence for the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k^3+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k^3+1}$$

What's the correct test to use here to test for convergence? My intuition would say that this doesn't converge since $2^k$ blows up faster than the denominator, but Im not quite sure how to show this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From ratio test,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{2^{k+1}}{2^k}\frac{k^3}{(k+1)^3}=2>1$$

Hence it diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct, the necessary condition $a_k \to 0$ is not satisfied, so it diverges. You can argue as follows: for $k \geq 10$ we have $k^3 \leq 2^k -1$ (prove), and so $2^k/(k^3+1) \geq 2^k/(2^k-1+1) = 1$ (just a random example how to formalize your idea of the numerator "blowing up faster than the denominator").

Answer (score 0):

Root test:

$(\frac{2^k}{k^3+1})^{1/k} \to 2 >1 $ as $k \to \infty.$